# container in Hyperledger fabric network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

what are the containers which are associated with each peer in Hyperledger Fabric (HLF)?

```
For example: Endorsing peers most have one chaincode container to execute chaincode.
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question very well, but I still would like to give it a try.

The docker containers associated with a peer are:

- Peer container, which manages you peer node. It's the peer container to which you send the transaction proposal either using CLI or through SDK. Every peer container embodies a copy of the ledger. The ledger is segregated using a channel.
- Couchdb container, which persists the world state. It saves every key-value pair which you query or invoke using chaincode. The name of the container is usually in the form `couchdb`.
- Chaincode container, where the chaincode is actually deployed. All the modules/packages that your chaincode requires are first installed when you instantiate your chaincode. The chaincode container usually have its name in the form `dev-peer0.org1.example.com-fabcar-1.0.1`, where `dev` refers to the environment in which the chaincode is instantiated. `peer0.org1.example.com` refers to the peer which instantiated it. `fabcar` here is the name of your chaincode and `1.0.1` is its version, which is changed every time you upgrade your chaincode.
  A peer might not have a chaincode container if it's only acting as a validating or committing peer.
- CLI container, this container is required for managing peers. At a time, CLI container can only manage a single peer. You can change the peer it's managing by adding/changing the environment variable `CORE_PEER_ADDRESS`, e.g. `CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051`.